# How can I display different text dependent on drop down menu?

Tags: html

For example, when user choose the option "boy", it will show the text "Tom" in bellow. If user choose another option "girl", it will show the text "Ava".

Comment: Would you please share what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer below code

```
    <html>
    <body>
   <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="girl">Girl</option>
   <option value="boy">Boy</option>
   </select>
   <div>
  <lable>Name: <span id="selectedName"></span></lable>
   </div>
   <script>
    function myFunction() {
    var gender =document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    switch(gender){
    case "boy":
    //alert("Tom");
    document.getElementById("selectedName").innerHTML = "Tom";
    break;
    case "girl":
   // alert("Ava");
   document.getElementById("selectedName").innerHTML = "Ava";
   break;
   default:

    document.getElementById("selectedName").innerHTML = "";
    }
}
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: How can i just show the text below in the option? but not show in the alert box.